# Diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory

The Diophantine equation $x^2+1=y^n$ $(x>0,n>1)$
has no solution with $x$ odd or $n$ even.

I've got the equation has no solution with n even hence n is odd.

What if x is odd?

Comment: Consider the remainder modulo an appropriate small prime power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V. A. Lebesgue has proved in $1850$ that the Diophantine equation $x^2+1=y^n$ has no solutions for positive integers $x,y$ and $n\ge 2$. For a modern proof see [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa65/aa6546.pdf), where the Diophantine equation
$$
x^2+C=y^n
$$
is studied for $C\in \mathbb{N}$. For the case $C=1$, the unique prime factorisation of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is used.